# Java Regex, capturing items inside of "[...]"

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to capture text inside of XML tags like ... and the content inside of strings like "[[A]]" that would be inside of the XML tags. So far my patterns are as follows:

```
    Pattern titleText = Pattern.compile("<title>([A-Z])</title>");
    Pattern extractLink = Pattern.compile("(\[\[([A-Z])\]\])");
```

I'm getting an error on the second pattern, and it's because of the `\`s. However, I'm not sure how to let Regex know that I want to escape the `[`s and `]`s so it captures the text *inside* of them.

An example of input I am trying to capture is:

```
<title>random text [[A]] more random text [[B]] ...</title>
```

Where `[[A]]` and `[[B]]` can happen any number of times, and I am trying to find all of them.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use \\ instead of \ in Java

Comment: What error are you getting on the second pattern?  It looks OK to me.

Comment: `Pattern titleText = Pattern.compile("<title>(.*?)</title>");`

Comment: My pattern is `Pattern extractLink = Pattern.compile("[[([A-Za-z ])]]");` and I am trying to catch any string inside of [[ ]]

Comment: so if there is text with `[[ hello how are you ]]` I want to extract `hello how are you`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extract a regex group in Java an arbitrary number of times without specifying each one in the pattern.  However, here is an alternative solution which splits the String on the bracketed item you want to match:

```
Pattern titleText = Pattern.compile("<title>(.*?)</title>");
String input = "<title>random text [[A]] more random text [[B]] ...</title>";
String text = "";

Matcher m = titleText.matcher(input);
if (m.find( )) {
    text = m.group(1);
}

String[] parts = text.split("\\[\\[");

for (int i=1; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    int index = parts[i].indexOf("]]");
    String match = parts[i].substring(0, index);
    System.out.println("Found a match: " + match);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Found a match: A
Found a match: B
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to write `String[] parts = text.split("\\[\\[");` for it to work for some reason...

Comment: @Zach ... brackets have a special regex meaning, so they need to be escaped.

Comment: Ah of course! But your original answer didn't include them!

Comment: Believe it or not, I answered your question on my cell phone!  Normally I test all my code on IntelliJ but at this moment it was not possible.

Comment: That's fine, thank you anyways again! I'm having another case issue though if you wouldn't mind helping me. Certain links can contain links inside, and that is the link I want, so I can have text like `[[ link here [[important link ]] ]]`. The split method that you implemented wont work for this case

Comment: @Zach May I suggest that you open a new question?  It would be difficult for me to give you a fully tested solution using only a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class TestTag {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String INPUT = "<title>random text [[ABBA]] more random text [[B]] ...</title>";
        String REGEX = "(\\[\\[\\S*]])";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);

        while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(" data: "
            + INPUT.substring(m.start() + 2, m.end() - 2));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Would you care to comment about how exactly your code solves the problem?